# If column has two values select one only

Tags: sql-server

I have the following data:

[image: Dataset]

If a Person has both 'Ramping' and 'Ramped' Status per Date then I want the result to return just SUM(Hours) per Date and Person where Status = 'Ramped'. Otherwise if they only have one Status then return the SUM(Hours) per Date and Person. The result I want is:

[image: Desired Result]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why does the second table have a value of `8` hours for `20180711`? If it's the `SUM` should, it not be `16`?

Comment: @Larnu "Where status = 'Ramped'". So if there are multiple states per day, then we only sum `Ramped` status for that day, so `8` for `11/07/2018`.

Comment: @JNevill yes, I see that now, the wording was a little confusing.

Comment: @Larnu, sorry the "where Status = 'Ramped'! was a late edition after posting. Thanks for you help guys, will check it out now

Answer (score 0):

use case statement to sum conditionally. Assuming that there are only 2 type of Status : Ramped & Ramping

```
select  Date, Person,
    status = min(Status),
    Hours   = case  when count(*) > 1
            then sum(case when Status = 'Ramped' then Hours else 0 end)
            else sum(Hours)
            end
from   yourtable
group by Date, Person
```

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, as the OP's data is an image (and I'm not retyping it out), however, one method would be by use of `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable YT
WHERE [Status] = 'Ramping'
   OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM YourTable e
                  WHERE e.[Date] = YT.[Date]
                    AND e.Person = YT.Person
                    AND e.[Status] = 'Ramping');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH x(D,Pr,status,H) AS
(
    SELECT GetDate(), 'A','1',8
    UNION ALL
    SELECT GetDate(), 'A','2',8
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT GetDate()-1, 'A','1',8       
)
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES  
    D,Pr,status,H
FROM x
ORDER BY 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY D,Pr ORDER BY Status)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since "Ramped < Ramping" (alphabetically), you could do a numbering of the ordered status values by person and date and then only take the first one(s), like here:

```
WITH numbering ([Date], Person, [Status], [Hours], Ranking) AS (
  SELECT [Date], Person, [Status], [Hours]
    , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Date], Person ORDER BY [Status])
  FROM YourTable WHERE [Status] IN ('Ramped', 'Ramping')
)
SELECT [Date], Person, [Status], [Hours]
FROM numbering
WHERE Ranking = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's name the original table as table1. Here is an example using CTE.

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT  [Date],[Person],[Status],sum([Hours]) as Hours, 
         row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY [Date],[Person] ORDER BY [Status]) AS rn
  FROM [LEGALDB2].[dbo].[table1]
  group by [Date],[Person],[Status]
  )
 select [Date],[Person],[Status],[Hours] 
 from cte
 where rn=1
```